# API GET request values cannot set to variables and echo using curl json_decode in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

Why can't I echo $phone_number in this code? It says

> Undefined index: phone_number. but when I echo `$response` it returns the values

```
    <?php

        $ch = curl_init( 'https://mighty-inlet-78383.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/imagedata');
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            die(curl_error($ch));
            echo 'No responce';
        }

        // Decode the response
        $responseData = json_decode($response);

        // Print the date from the response
        $phone_number = $responseData['phone_number'];
        echo $phone_number;
   ?>
```

Comment: Because there are nested arrays. Try `$responseData[0]['phone_number'];` And you need to use the true attribute in your `json_decode()` statement to make it an array

Comment: @JayBlanchard now it shows this error `Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Because you didn't make it an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these are arrays within arrays you need to go one level deeper to get the data you want. First, make sure you're returning the JSON as an array, using the 'true' attribute:

```
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);
```

Then you can get the first phone number (or any phone number by changing the array index):

```
echo $responseData[0]['phone_number'];
echo $responseData[1]['phone_number'];
```

You can also loop through the responses:

```
foreach($responseData AS $response) {
    echo $response['phone_number'];
}
```